# How to copy animation attributes to multiple objects?

Tags: animation

Very basic question here, I am afraid.

I have hundreds of shattered pieces of a mesh and I am trying to animate their visibility over the scene.

How can I animate the visibility and render visibility parameter for one piece, then copy/transfer to all the others?

[image]

Comment: Your objects are already in a group right? If yes, the answers of this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/cannot-keyframe-visibility-in-outliner-groups-view are maybe helpful. Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/python-stop-motion-insert-keyframe

Comment: I was hoping for a very "handy" solution like a "copy animation" or something similar. Can't figure out why it's not possible to simply copy and paste one f-curve from one obj to others

Comment: Ahh, ok. Try to create a sample object, animate it, select all desired objects (last one should be the sample object) and press *Ctrl + L > Animation Data*. I can not test it at the moment, but it could work :)

Comment: Poor 23: Perfect! It works! 
thank you so much!!

Answer (score 11):

Link the *Animation Data* of the active object to the other selected objects via *Make Links* menu:

[image]

1. Create an *Empty* (or every other type of object) and *animate it* (according to the scene)
2. Select all desired objects and finally the *Empty* to make it the active object
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select *Animation Data*

[image]
*Object visibility animation*

**Note:** Since all those objects now share a single Action datablock you can update the animation on any one of the objects and the change will be shared by all the other objects.  If in the future you need to be able to edit the animation of one without affecting all the others, you can use the N-panel pop-out of the NLA editor, or use the Dope Sheet's Action Editor mode and click the Make Single User button (this will make a copy of the action so it is not shared with the others).

[image]

Comment: Great and simple way to solve it.
Thanks so much again

Comment: The reason this works is that after you perform the Make Links operation all those objects share a single Action datablock.  I would not say that it is "driven by one Empty" because you can remove that Empty and the action still exists and is shared.  Changes to that action will be shared by all the objects.  The fact that they are shared is not entirely obvious because the `[n]` button to make a single-user copy is only illustrated in some less-used UI elements such as the N-panel pop-out of the NLA editor, and in the footer of the Dope Sheet's Action Editor mode.

Comment: Is there a chance to limit the link to just visibilty animation data? I have multiple properties animated but just want to link the visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Consider.
A driver.
In the image below a parent object visibility drives another.

[image]

The purple render icon indicates a driver is active

[image]

This menu show how one can copy and paste a driver. Earlier you would see create driver.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this also very usefull information. But i think that the solution from Poor23 is the simplest one.
Use CTRL + L -> Animation data
(sorry for my basic English)