# Antimation-how to make object visible then invisible

Tags: animation

I am creating a small antimation, where I need a few objects. One which is text to appear then disappear, and one object to disappear at a given frame setting(s).

I know the eye button in the outliner can do this, but how do I work that in using key frames?

Comment: which renderer are you using ? Here it is matter of setting nodes with a mix shader (your shader and transparency) and the factor of the mix shader is frame driven

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38373/how-to-copy-animation-attributes-to-multiple-objects/

Comment: Cycles render (of course ;) )

Comment: If you want it to fade in and out you will need to keyframe the alpha.  If you just want it to disappear abruptly then keyframe the hide_render property (which looks like an old-school reel film movie camera) which is different from the hide property (eyeball) as is discussed in the two answers.

Comment: na mine is just appering and disapeering no fades --- :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ***Blender Internal*** you may achieve it keyframing the *alpha transparency* values. E.g. in frame 1 hover the cursor over the Alpha slider with the value set to *1.000* and press <kbd>I</kbd> to keyframe it. Then go to frame 2, change the alpha value to *0.000* and keyframe it again.
[image]

In ***Cycles*** you can keyframe the Fac value of the *Mix Shader* (which mixes your shader with Transparent shader).
[image]

Comment: OK I'm doing the Nodes for cycles, How do you reset the I when it goes wrong to fix it, and how do you get rid of it all together and start over. I have my dope sheet up but do Not know how to delete just the ones attaced to one object without deleteing everything within the dope sheet.

Comment: Hover your cursor over the *Fac* slider of the Mix Shader, then RMB--> *Delete/Replace Keyframe* to remove/change a single one or *Clear Keyframes* to start over. You can adjust the periods between keyframes using a Dope Sheet Editor. Making the spacing between keyframes bigger allows you to fade the object out.

Comment: thank you... I was getting into the habbit of box select delete all of the keyframes in dope editor but when I got to more than one objecct it was getting rediculious .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you want to make something appear in frame ten and then dissappear at frame 20. At frame 0 go to outliner and click camera icon (eye only hide things from 3D view, not from render) and press "I" while hovering still over the camera icon and you see that it create keyframe for it. Now go to frame 10 and click camera icon again to make it visible on render and while hovering over press "I" again to make keyframe... at frame 20 do same that you did in frame 0. I have used to make keyframes for both, eye icon and camera icon, so same things would happen also in rendered view and in 3D view.