# How can I keyframe multiple (like 300) objects' show/hide property?

Tags: objects, keyframes, visibility

I would need to know how to keyframe multiple (like 300) objects' show/hide property?

Comment: [_3Descape](https://twitter.com/_3Descape) on Twitter provided a very creative solution, [make a new shared strip in NLA](https://twitter.com/_3Descape/status/931206386490445825).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution would be to add a custom property to the scene that reflects the desired visibility state of the objects, and some Python code to apply that desired state to the actual objects.

```
import bpy

def interesting(ob) -> bool:
    """Returns True for objects to show/hide, and False otherwise.

    Alter to suit your needs.
    """

    return ob.name.startswith('Plane')

def hide_or_show(self, context=None):
    hide = self.hide_manus_objects
    for ob in self.objects:
        if not interesting(ob):
            continue
        # Change to ob.hide to hide from viewport instead of from render.
        # Or use ob.hide = ob.hide_render = hide to change both.
        ob.hide_render = hide


# Some cleanup in case you're running this multiple times.
try:
    del bpy.types.Scene.hide_manus_objects
except AttributeError:
    pass

# Responds to manual changes to the property.
bpy.types.Scene.hide_manus_objects = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name='hide_manus_objects', update=hide_or_show)
# Handles frame changes and thus responds to animation data.
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(hide_or_show)

# Write to the property once to make it show up in the properties panel.
bpy.context.scene.hide_manus_objects = bpy.context.scene.hide_manus_objects
```

This does require you to alter the `interesting()` function to return `True` for those objects that you want to manage with this. Given that you have 300-ish objects, I'm assuming that there is some naming scheme that'll make this possible.

To use the code, just paste it into a text block and press "Run Script". If you want to have it active every time you open the blend file (you probably do), make sure the name of the text block ends in `.py` and enable the "Register" checkbox before saving.

Comment: I am testing this Python script, and I think there is a missing information here on where and how to trigger this function?

Comment: There is the paragraph that starts with "to use this code...."

Comment: I'm confused how this works. Should I create the custom property for the parent object or what?

Comment: Oh, and of course, thank you for the time you've put into this answer! :)

Comment: The script creates the property, you'll find it in the scene custom properties panel.

Comment: I still don't get it to work, nothing selected hides or keyframes, and nothing shows up into the scene custom properties panel. What should I do? Here's my blend: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48396

Comment: Well, the idea is that you alter the code that says "Alter to suit your needs". I also noticed that the custom property only shows up after a value has been written to it, so I added that in the script (the last line).

Comment: OOooohhh, now I got it! :D I was a bit too much of an artist for reading the actual comments in the code. All clear now! Wheeeeee!

Comment: And PHEW! What a nice thing I had an unique name for the object that I had copied all over the scene 1827 times to be precise here :) And yes, I only need to unhide them for the viewport (by using the ob.hide :) for the playback to be smooth on other parts of the timeline.

Answer (score 10):

Create an *Empty*, keyframe its *Visibility* property, select all the objects you'd like to hide/show, select the newly created *Empty*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to open up *Make Links* menu and select *Animation Data*.

[image]

Credit for the idea goes to @p2or, see: [How to copy animation attributes to multiple objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38437/31447)

Comment: Nice alternative solution and a nice gif! Even though this don't really work if the child objects already have some animation in them

Comment: This is a kind of thing Blender is good at, hacky way, but link happy.

Comment: I guess this worked in Blender 2.7 but in later versions of Blender the keyframes become hidden when the Empty is disabled making this approach very unmanageable, a better solution is needed.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative solution:

1. manually select all objects you want to show/hide;
2. alt-click the eye-icon or the render-icon in the outliner to show/hide them (in resp. the viewport or the render);
3. run this script in a text block:

   ```
   import bpy

   for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
       ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render")
       ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide")
   ```

This is more manual work (you have to click around a lot more), and it produces 300-ish fcurves that you'll have to manually manage (rather than my other answer, which results in one fcurve only). However, the code is simpler, so if that floats your boat, use this approach

Comment: Great! Nice touch with the alt-clicking the eye-icon, I always forget this feature exists! One way also is, if you've border-selected the objects in the outliner, to right-click one of them and 'Toggle Visible'

Comment: Also worth noting, at first when you press 'Run Script' it seems like nothing happens, you need to move on the timeline before the keyframes are put.

Comment: And now I realized, how can you run the script when the objects are hidden... this might not work after all

Comment: well that's why I first opted for a script that "knows" which objects you're dealing with. Of course it can be altered to loop over all objects in a group, all children of a certain empty, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is this commercial add-on, **[Key Selected Objects](https://blastframe.com/product/key-selected-objects/)**, which lets you add/delete keys for multiple objects from the user interface. You could select your objects then keyframe the visibility for the Viewports and Renders:
[image: Key Selected Objects]

Answer (score 0):

If using Nodes Add-On, you can do it this way:

SVERCHOK:
[image]

ANIMATION NODES:

[image]
[image]

Although, keyframing "node" is not as clear cut (not visible on the graph editor). There is a way around it by using controller that drives the node.

I would use Dr.Sybren answer above for now...